# Swift Package Manager Changing Location URLS

Tags: swift, git, swift-package-manager

We have noticed on a project that when are including package.resolved in source control, depending on which developer checks out the code, package.resolved is changing its location URL on git repositories to sometimes include '.git' in the url, and other times not. This is causing merge conflicts when nothing is really needed to change.

```
EX:
Developer A commits package.resolved:
location: "https://github.com/githubtraining/hellogitworld"

Developer B commits package.resolved
location: "https://github.com/githubtraining/hellogitworld.git"
```

Is this a problem with local git settings on each developers machine, or is there something in the respoitories we can fix to alter this behaviour?

Comment: Git itself doesn't do much special here: the servers will often add or remove `.git` suffixes automatically so that you can `git clone https://github.com/user/repo` *or* `git clone https://github.com/user/repo.git` and the server will serve up the same repository. Your Git *client* simply records the URL that *you used*. Whether there's a Swift package manager setting to "clean" these things, I have no idea, but that's probably the best way to handle this. Your other option is to just try to educate your developers to use a consistent pattern.